# awk iterating through an array using for loop and printing based on if condition

Tags: arrays, if-statement, for-loop, awk, cut

```
   bash --version
```

bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

> cat filename.txt|cut -d "|" -f1|tr -d [^:digit:][:punct:]
>   [:blank:]|tail -10|awk '{a[i++]=$0;}{k=length(a)}END{for
>   (i=k;i>=1;i--)if (5==5){print i "     "a[i]" " a[i-1]" "k}}'

```
10            10
9  18410      10
8 18410 18409 10
7 18409 18408 10
6 18408 18407 10
5 18407 18406 10
4 18406 18405 10
3 18405 18404 10
2 18404 18403 10
1 18403 18402 10


cat filename.txt|cut -d "|" -f1|tr -d [^:digit:][:punct:]   [:blank:]|tail -10|awk '{a[i++]=$0;}{k=length(a)}END{for (i=k;i>=1;i--)if ((a[i]-1)==a[i-1]){print i " "a[i] " "k} else print "not done"}'

not done
not done
not done
not done
not done
not done
not done
not done
not done
not done
```

trying to get the greatest number `x` if the preceding number is one lesser than `x`.

`wc -l` does not give the row count that I need.  I dont need line count.

Column extracted using `cut` is the primary key in this csv file.
File could have unknown number of blank lines at the end.

```
 cat filename.txt|cut -d "|" -f1|tr -d [^:digit:][:punct:]    [:blank:]|tail -10
18402
18403
18404
18405
18406
18407
18408
18409
18410
```

Why is this if condition evaluating to take the "else action"?
(a[i]-1==a[i-1]) evaluates to false. I dont see why.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is, could you be more explicit about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get the row count from my pipe delimited file, this is what the file looks like
 cat filename.txt|cut -d "|" -f1|tr -d [^:digit:][:punct:][:blank:]|tail -10
18402
18403
18404
18405
18406
18407
18408
18409
18410

Comment: Does it make sense now? Something silly that i am missing, maybe.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? I get `not done` only for the first string.

Comment: My version of `tr` does not recognize the caret in `[^:digit:]`..

Comment: @user3146086, here is what I tried: http://pastebin.com/JaUVSayr

Comment: yes sure. please paste the code you tried. I thought awk recognizes datatypes itself. anyway I tried with +0 also, for awk to realize number datatype.try [:alpha:] instead of [^:digit:]. Please suggest some other workaround with or without awk.

Comment: the if condition is evaluating exactly as you demonstrated xaizek. Verified what I ran again in vain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following CSV file (`filename.txt`):

```
1a|b|123
2a|b|123
3|4
5.7|4
66
67
10|11
11|aaa
```

we can determine the number 67 using:

```
awk -f s.awk filename.txt
```

where `s.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="|"
}
NF>=1 {
    q=$1
    gsub(/([^[:digit:]])|([[:blank:][:punct:]])*/,"",q)
    if (q==(prev+1))
        if (q>max)
            max=q
    prev=q
}
END {
    print "Max=" max
}
```

**Update**

A one-liner could look like:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { q=$1; gsub(/([^[:digit:]])|([[:blank:][:punct:]])*/,"",q); if (q==(prev+1)) {if (q>max) max=q} prev=q } END { print "Max=" max }' filename.txt
```

Comment: need a one-liner, Thanks for your response though.

Comment: this works!! I thought awk is crippled for large files, made it to loop through only ten lines in the one liner I wrote, anyway that does not work, this one works for now, will have to test it though
Thanks

Comment: @user3146086 That is great!

Comment: @user3146086 Yes, I was not able to move the discussion to stackoverflow chat since you had too small reputation.. :)

Comment: @user3146086 I have question for you: How does actually your first field look like? Is it necessary to do all the replacements in `gsub(/([^[:digit:]])|([[:blank:][:punct:]])*/,"",q)` ?

Comment: this is a file created by some windows based tool with @^ symbols after each character,same applies for the first field

Comment: @user3146086 Ok, I see.. Can you give an example of a typical first field?

Comment: I used this one finally, it works, thanks a ton Håkon Hægland  awk ' { FS="|" } { q=$1}; { gsub(/([[:alpha:][:cntrl:][:blank:][:space:][:punct:]])/,"",q)};{a[i++]=q;k=length(a);} END {for (i=k;i>=1;i--)if (((a[i]-1)==a[i-1])||((a[i]-1)==a[i-2])||((a[i]-1)==a[i-3])||((a[i]-1)==a[i-4])||((a[i]-1)==a[i-5])) break; {print a[i]} }' filename.txt